# Add Background Movie Clip with Python

Tags: python, camera

I'll have to rotoscope some movie clips with different resolution and frame rate.

I'm trying to write a script to help, but I did'nt manage to add the film in the Background Images properties of the camera data.

[image: view of the code that doesn't work]

here's the script so far

```
import os 
import bpy 
import ffmpeg

#add movie clip and configure path and name variable 
videoFile = "/home/xxx/xxxxx/videotheque-2/videos/test_video.mp4" 
videoFilepath = os.path.dirname(videoFile) 
videoFilename = os.path.basename(videoFile)

#get metadata
videoMetadata = ffmpeg.probe(videoFile)
video_stream = next((stream for stream in videoMetadata['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)

videoWidth = int(video_stream['width'])
videoHeight = int(video_stream['height'])
videoFramerate = int(video_stream['r_frame_rate'].strip("/1"))
videoTotalFrames = int(video_stream['nb_frames'])

print ("filepath: ", videoFilepath, "filename: ", videoFilename, "Resolution = ", videoWidth, "x", videoHeight, "Total Frames = ", videoFramerate, "Total Frames = ", videoTotalFrames )

#Configure Camera Background
bpy.ops.object.select_camera() bpy.context.object.data.show_background_images = True
bpy.context.object.data.background_images.new()
bpy.context.object.data.background_images[0].source = 'MOVIE_CLIP'

#part that doesn't work
bpy.ops.clip.open(directory=videoFilepath, files=[{"name":videoFilename, "name":videoFilename}], relative_path=False)

#Configure Scene 
#Format - Resolution
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = videoWidth
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = videoHeight
#Format - Frame Rate
bpy.context.scene.render.fps = videoFramerate
#Frame Range
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_start + videoTotalFrames
```

Any clues on how to find a way to make it work? (I'm not a developer, please don't beat me!)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [Camera - set background image - python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151162/camera-set-background-image-python) (Thanks to Robert Gützkow)

Here is the new code, which uses a video instead of an image:

```
# Configure Camera Background
img = bpy.data.images.load(videoFile)
cam.data.show_background_images = True
bg = cam.data.background_images.new()
bg.image = img
img.source = 'MOVIE'
bpy.context.object.data.background_images[0].image_user.frame_duration = videoTotalFrames
bpy.context.object.data.background_images[0].image_user.frame_start = 1
```